# Facing errors while walking trough data with os.walk()

Tags: python, json, graph, twitter, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to identify twitter relation and did the following steps to read the dataset

```
import os

for (dir_path, dir_names, file_names) in os.walk('../materials/data/friend_relationships/'):
    files = file_names


for file_name in files:
    with open('../materials/data/friend_relationships/' + file_name) as p:
        pair_data = json.load(p)
        for k in pair_data.keys():
            twitter_pair = k.split()
            if pair_data[k]['relationship']['source']['following'] is True:
                pairs.append((str(twitter_pair[0]), str(twitter_pair[1])))
            elif pair_data[k]['relationship']['source']['followed_by'] is True:
                pairs.append((str(twitter_pair[1]), str(twitter_pair[0])))
```

however, it is giving me an error of
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

please help. thanks in advance

Comment: I think your indentation broke while copying to here. Furthermore, did you try checking if the files open properly and contain the data you're expecting (for example by just printing the first line or two)?

Comment: JSONDecodeError means the file at '../materials/data/friend_relationships/' + file_name was not a valid JSON file. An error at line 1 column 1 (char 0) means the file either didn't start with a "{" or was empty. Maybe there are some non-JSON files mixed in with that directory

Comment: Also, you should replace open('../materials/data/friend_relationships/' + file_name) with open(os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)). It might not matter in this case, but os.walk is recursive! If you don't want to walk recursively, just use os.listdir